# Functions not running

Tags: android, sleep

I'm trying to pause a thread briefly while I show a message, but when I try to run the application, it doesn't run the code preceding the sleep until AFTER the sleep is complete (or at least doesn't update the UI).

```
public void toPause(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textView);
    textView.setText("Waiting...");

    SystemClock.sleep(500);

    textView.setText("Finished.");
}
```

Is there any way to update the UI in conjunction with sleep()? Or will I have to use a handler? Thanks.

Edit: I have also tried separating it into separate functions.

Comment: Are you intentionally putting a sleep or is there a long running task involved? If there is a long running task, then using AsncTask with progress dialog might be worth considering.

Comment: Sleep is just plain evil in most situations, and this is one of them!  Why sleep?  You should need a certificate in advanced Java threading before you use sleep and the compiler should give you a million warnings you need to click through before you can use sleep ;)

Comment: To answer your question.  When you setText(), a message is posted to the message queue on the UI thread.  You then stop the UI thread from doing anything, including processing the messages on it's queue, until the sleep finishes.  Therefore, it cannot update the UI until the thread wakes again.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I figured that must be what was happening. I was being stubborn trying to find some way to force it to process queue messages before it reaches the sleep because I don't understand Async; back to the books!